# pdo transaction on one update

Tags: pdo

Will using pdos

```
$dbc -> beginTransaction();
$q = $dbc -> prepare("UPDATE ............... ");
$dbc -> commit();
```

Increase performance when doing one update?

Or is it only when doing multiple queries?

Answer (score 1):

Nope, there is no point in using a transacton for just a single query.

Answer (score -2):

From the documentation:

> Calling PDO::prepare() and PDOStatement::execute() for statements that will be issued multiple times with different parameter values optimizes the performance of your application by allowing the driver to negotiate client and/or server side caching of the query plan and meta information...

To me this means that PDO::prepare() is specifically optimizing performance for multiple queries. Whether or not 'optimized for multiple queries' == 'overhead for one query' is likely up to you to determine through implementation and testing.